# Android TextView has unwanted thin black lines above and below

Tags: android, textview

I am using TextViews to render talk bubbles, which are formed from 9-patch .png images stretched to fit whatever a character says. The same TextView is programmatically reused, resized, and shifted to different places on the screen as the conversation occurs.

Everything looks good except sometimes there is a thin (probably 1 pixel) black line above and below, at the edges of the TextView space (the .png's themselves have a transparent background).

I've been searching online for a week, but found no one with this exact same complaint or any solutions based on anything even vaguely similar.

Any thoughts?

[added by request: .xml and screenshot (suddenly this morning my reputation went up to 11 -- woohoo!)]

```
<FrameLayout    
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"   
tools:context=".ActivityPreMomGirl"
android:background="@drawable/bg_pre_mom_girl"
android:id="@+id/mom_girl_cb" >    

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/talk_chat"        
    android:background="@drawable/talk_chat"           
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"          
    android:visibility="invisible" />

</FrameLayout>
```

[image: Black lines barely visible, but clearer and more unsightly in reality.]

Comment: Can you post a screen shot?

Comment: I just took a screenshot, but when I went to post it, it said that I had to have 10 reputation to post images. Don't know how to get reputation ...

Comment: Anyway, like I said, they are just very thin black lines at top and bottom of TextView. I'll keep the screenshot ready to go in case my reputation goes up in the near future ;)

Comment: Post it on cloud, or imgur or something for now.

Comment: Also post your xml layout file.

Comment: .xml and screenshot added. The black lines are pretty vague in the image, but they look much worse in reality.

Comment: @Weeman are you sure your 9-patch image is well done and doesn't contain any artefact? Can you post it here?

Comment: are you sure the black lines aren't part of the image?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `TextView`? If you want to show text on some background why not to use `ImageView`.

Comment: Because the focus of my manipulations is on the text not the image. The code is set up to programmatically calculate the number of lines and exact size of the text to output and then resizes the bubble to fit it. The bubble is just a background image.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was solved by adding "android:background="@android:color/transparent" to the EditText element